# Reading a Base64 image in front-end with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm setting up a project, and I decided that the best alternative was to save the images in Base64 and save it in the database.
This is OK, all right.
However, when I need to render them on the front end, the following is not working, for some reason, can someone help me?

```
<img class="whatever" src="<%= datasetresult[1].photo%>">
```

When I look at the browser console, Base64 is there, so I don't understand why it isn't rendering.

HELP!

**EDIT**

[image: That is the console of Chrome]

Comment: You need to prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64,` (if you have a jpeg image) before your base64 string. Edit : wrote an answer for better readability.

Comment: But when I look through the navedagor console, that data is already there! Look into the edit

Comment: Can you give us the base64 image using pastebin ? Also, you are using `data:image/png;base64,`. Are you sure your image is a png image, and not a jpeg image ?

Comment: Yeah, the image is a png, the base64 code is generated inside the system itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` tag of images can accept base64 strings, if you specify the type. For example, if you have a jpeg image, you need to prefix the base64 string with `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.

If you have SVG (with or without raster data), you need to use `data:image/svg+xml;base64,`.